# apt-install specific package from testing repository only

Tags: repository, apt

I have added the Raspbian testing repository to my `sources.list` so I can install the `rtl_433` package.

However, I only really want that package from the testing repository (plus and dependencies). For everything else I want to stick to the standard Buster repository.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the priority for apt. The default prio is 500. Packages with higher prio are preferred.

Create a prio file in

> /etc/apt/preferences.d/[yourrandomfilename]

In this file configure a high prio for the package(s) you want, and a low prio for all else in this repo. So something like:

```
Package: *
Pin: origin test-repo
Pin-Priority: 400

Package: rtl_433*
Pin: origin test-repo
Pin-Priority: 600
```

[have a look at this explanation here](https://www.pcsuggest.com/apt-pinning-install-and-upgrade-debian-packages-selectively/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can force the install from the testing repository by using the `-t` option

```
apt install -t test-repo rtl_433
```

Reference: https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration?action=show&redirect=AptPreferences

Comment: I tried that, but I think you have to add the repository to the `sources.list` first and without changing the priorities, everything then comes from testing as it has newer versions in it.

Comment: I see your point now. Have you looked into tools such as [aptly] (https://www.aptly.info/)?